Multi-loop systems block reduction techniques
Do I start by multiplying 18/s+3 * 1/s+3 = 18/(s+3)^(2)?
Then is it (18/(s+3)^(2))/(1+(18/(s+3)^(2)*4)) = 18 / ((s + 3)^2 * (72 / (s + 3)^2 + 1))?


You can reformat in latex to make it easier to read. For instance 18/(s+3)^(2) becomes $\dfrac{18}{(s+3)^2}$ by using this:  \$\dfrac{18}{(s+3)^2}\$ <-- you ought to show your steps too because of the poor/difficult format of your final formula and, the lack of steps make it tricky to follow what you did.

The most left part in the 2nd line is still correct - however, the most right part is wrong. After multiplying both - numerator and denominator - with (s+3)² the whole expression reduces to
18/[(s+3)² + 72].
But note that this expression is the transfer function of the small inner loop only.

Do I then multiply that by the Gain of 50?

Is $\dfrac{900}{s^2+6s+81}$ the correct answer?

@ NonComposMentis No - I don`t think so (the last numer (81) is not correct.)

@NonComposMentis No. It's $\frac{900}{s^2,+,6s,+,981}$: ratsimp(solve(Eq(((vin-vout)*50-4*vout)*18/(s+3)*1/(s+3),vout),vout)[0]/vin)

@ periblepsis Instead of 972 I arrive at (972+9).....ahh I see, you have corrected the constant term.

@LvW Note I corrected it. I picked up a partial value instead of the sum. But noticed immediately. I'm +1 your answer and don't plan to try and answer here. None of what I said is really going to help the OP with block simplification. And I don't want to go that route, anyway. The OP probably needs to show work.

@ periblepsis OK, I agree with you. However, another interesting question related to the shown circuit would be:  What is the phase margin ? Is there only one margin? Or perhaps two or even three margins (because there are three different alternatives to open the loops) ?
